# Every time I run the code an error keeps coming saying,"TypeError: raw_input() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given"

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, raw-input

```
bird_names="kiwi, hawk, crow, penguin"  
count=0 
bird_guess=input("Guess the name of the bird that may be in the secret list.You will only get 3 
chances")  
while count<3:  
    if bird_guess.lower() in bird_names.lower():  
        print("Congrats! Correct guess!")  
        break  
   else:  
        count=count+1  
        ans = str(3 - count)
```

The statement mentioned below contains some sort of problem which I am unable to understand:

```
bird_guess=input("Wrong guess! Try again! Only",ans,"chances are left!")
```

It shows TypeError, saying that raw_input() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to do string concatenation, change your input to:

```py
bird_guess=input("Wrong guess! Try again! Only " + str(ans) + " chances are left!")
```

or you can use string interpolation like so

```py
bird_guess=input(f"Wrong guess! Try again! Only {ans} chances are left!")
```

Comment: I have already tried your first suggestion but the same error keeps on displaying.

Comment: You're probably doing the same thing somewhere else in your code, check all of your inputs and their respective strings